# Limiting the Content Script of a Chrome Extension to Run Only in a Specific Tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I'm working on a Chrome extension that records user interactions on web sites and keeps track of them. By injecting a script or function into web pages to record user actions, the plugin makes use of chrome.scripting. The content script or function, however, should only be allowed to run in the tab where the user starts the recording. I want the content script or function to activate in all URLs open in that tab once the recording is engaged in that particular tab.

So far, I've been successful in creating a content script that, when the extension is active, successfully injects my recording capabilities into web pages using chrome.scripting. The content script applied to all URLs rather than just the one I desired when I tried to programmatically inject it using the chrome.scripting.registerContentScript API, though. I also looked into using the tabs permission found in the manifest.json file, however this simply gave me access to tab data and didn't provide a way to restrict content scripts to particular tabs.
In order to prevent it from running in any other open tabs in the browser, I need to inject a content script or function into each URL within the single tab where the user enables the recording.

Comment: The only ways are 1) inject explicitly via executeScript inside chrome.webNavigation or chrome.webRequest listener but it won't always achieve document_start timing, 2) use `chrome.debugger` API to attach to this tab and then use [Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument) command.